# ERROR: Pool de conexión Glassfish 4.0 con MySQL 8 - Servidor AWS

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish, aws, keystore

Tengo un sevidor EC2 y RDS en AWS, en EC2 tengo desplegado Glassfish 4.0.0 donde voy a desplegar una aplicación, sin embargo estoy creando el pool de conexión a una base de datos MySQL 8 en un servidor RDS, sin embargo al hacer ping a la base de datos desde el Glassfish sale el siguiente error:

*Ping Connection Pool failed for mailPool. Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/home/ubuntu/glassfish-4.0/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/mail/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect] Please check the server.log for more details.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo al utilizar las mismos propiedades adicionales conectándome desde DBeaver si lo permite.

El driver de conexión que estoy utilizando en el glassfish es mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar y dentro de la configuración de dominio si se encuentra el archivo Keystore.jks.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber como se puede solucionar este error ya que borre el dominio y continuo igual, no se si es por el driver de conexión o la versión de la base de datos que no es compatible con ese glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

Este error se soluciono agregando la propiedad adicional useSSL con valor false en el pool de conexión ya que estaba solicitando desactivar la conexión a la base de datos con SSL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Estuve buscando ésta solución durante días.
Por qué será que configurando ese parámetro si funciona?

Comment: Puntua la respuesta y la pregunta por favor. Esto se debe a la versión del contenedor ya que requiere que se le indique si la conexión a realizar usara SSL